# Why does Moody tell Harry about the Trace?

Tags: harry-potter

Hey I was wondering why in *Deathly Hallows Part 1* Moody tells Harry of the Trace. Why is that relevant to his safety? The information on his whereabouts would be only sent to the Ministry once he performed magic. Did Moody think the Ministry would be infiltrated by Voldemort and thus could track Harry like that before the charm was broken?

Comment: He didn't think Voldemort would infiltrate the Ministry. The Order of the Phoenix thought (knew?) that Voldemort **already had** infiltrated the Ministry. I'm pretty sure that's made really clear in both the book and the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what Moody thought. And it turns out he was right, as Death Eaters did infiltrate the Ministry and assassinated the minister. The new minister, Pius Thicknesse, was under Imperio curse, controlled by Death Eaters.

Answer (score 1):

## The Dark Lord was  able to get information from the Ministry.

By the time the Order was trying to transport Harry out of Number 4 Privet Drive, the Dark Lord had control of several Ministry wizards, including the Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, Pius Thicknesse. Moody explains this to Harry when he explains about the Trace.

> “The Trace, the Trace!’ said Mad-Eye impatiently. ‘The charm that detects magical activity around under-seventeens, the way the Ministry finds out about under-age magic! If you, or anyone around you, casts a spell to get you out of here, Thicknesse is going to know about it, and so will the Death Eaters.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 4 (The Seven Potters)*</sup></sub>

So, yes - Moody was telling Harry that the Dark Lord could use the Trace to his advantage and track Harry by using information the Ministry would pass on to him.